# mongodb gridfs carrierwave or joint or other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper, gridfs

i want to store all my assets in mongo gridfs.   i was trying to get 
carrierwave setup with mongomapper and gridfs but seems carrierwave 
supports mongoid now instead.

I need to be able to save different size versions / cropped versions 
of an image so thats why i was going to use carrierwave.   Currently 
its set up to store on file system using paperclip but paperclip is 
not easy or i have not found a good way to store in gridfs. ??

Should i be using joint to store assts ? but then how do i create 
versions etc ?

I basically have muliple models that can have many assets.  My models 
are mongomapper documents / embedded docs, so i could use mongoid for 
my assets model and use carrierwave ....?

please can any one help with the best solution to this ?  and 
hopefully point me to good examples!

thanks alot 
rick

Answer (score 0):

I recommend joint and just storing originals. From there, you can create alternate versions on the fly. I have used http://github.com/quirkey/imanip on projects to create alternate sizes. On the first request I typically cache the original to the file system for speedier requests and then create/cache the requested version/size.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend carrierwave, because if you decide, for whatever reason, to change file stores (for example, if you want to move to a filesystem-based store instead), it will be much easier with carrierwave.

There is a carrierwave plugin called mm-carrierwave that lets you use carrierwave with MongoMapper.